# Does not work message. Primefaces

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

I use next page. And a method of managedBean works, but not show message:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            template="/templates/template.xhtml">
<ui:define name="metadata">
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:body>
    <h:form id="form">

        <p:growl id="msgs1" showDetail="true" />



    <!--    <p:outputLabel rendered="#{projectBean.before}" value="registration is not open yet"/>

        <p:outputLabel rendered="#{projectBean.after}" value="registration was closed"/>

        <p:panel header="#{msg['createProject']}" id="panel" rendered="#{projectBean.checkDate}">-->
        <p:panel header="#{msg['createProject']}" id="panel" >

            <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="7" id = "panelGrd">
                <h:outputLabel for="name" value="#{msg['name']}*" style="width:100px"/>

                <p:inputText id="name" value="#{project.name}" label="#{msg['name']}"  style=" padding: 10px; width:400px"
                             validatorMessage="Name - please input english letters, digits only"
                             required="true">
                    <f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-zA-Z\s\d]+$" />
            </p:inputText>
                <p:message for="name" display="icon" />


                <h:outputText value="&#160;" /><h:outputText value="&#160;" /><h:outputText value="&#160;" />

                <h:outputLabel for="meta" value="#{msg['meta']}*" />
                <p:inputText id="meta" value="#{project.meta}" label="#{msg['meta']}"  style=" padding: 10px; width:400px"
                             validatorMessage="Meta - please input english letters, digits only"
                             required="true">
                <f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-zA-Z\s\d]+$" />
                </p:inputText>
                <p:message for="meta" display="icon" />


                <h:outputText value="&#160;" /><h:outputText value="&#160;" /><h:outputText value="&#160;" />

                <h:outputLabel for="des" value="#{msg['description']}*" />
                <p:inputTextarea rows="5" cols="30" id="des" counter="display" maxlength="250"
                                 counterTemplate="{0} #{msg['charactersRemaining']}."  value="#{project.description}"
                                 label="#{msg['description']}"  autoResize="false"  style=" padding: 10px; width:400px "
                                 validatorMessage="Description - please input english letters, digits only"
                                 required="true">
                    <f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-zA-Z\s\d]+$" />
                </p:inputTextarea>
                <p:message for="des" display="icon" />



                <h:outputText value="&#160;" /><h:outputText id="display" /><h:outputText value="&#160;" />
                <h:outputText value="&#160;" /><h:outputText value="&#160;" /><h:outputText value="&#160;" />

                <h:outputLabel for="amount2" value="#{msg['sphere']}" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="amount2"  value="#{project.sphere}" label="#{msg['sphere']}"  style="width:400px">

                    <f:selectItems value="#{enumValuesProvider.spheres}"
                                   var="sphere"
                                   itemValue="#{sphere}"
                                   itemLabel="#{sphere.name}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <h:outputText value="&#160;" />

                <h:outputText value="&#160;" /><h:outputText value="&#160;" /><h:outputText value="&#160;" />

                <h:outputLabel for="pattern" value="#{msg['manager']}*" />
                <p:inputText id="pattern" value="#{project.manager}" label="#{msg['manager']}"  style=" padding: 10px; width:400px"
                             validatorMessage="Manager - please input english letters, digits only"
                             required="true">
                <f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-zA-Z\s\d]+$" />
                </p:inputText>
                <p:message for="pattern" display="icon" />


                <h:outputText value="&#160;" /><h:outputText value="&#160;" /><h:outputText value="&#160;" />

                <h:outputLabel for="checked" value="#{msg['team']}" />
                <p:inputText id="checked" value="#{project.team}"   style=" padding: 10px; width:400px"
                             validatorMessage="Team - please input english letters, digits only" >
                <f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-zA-Z\s\d]+$" />
                </p:inputText>
                <p:message for="checked" display="icon" />


                <h:outputText value="&#160;" /><h:outputText value="&#160;" /><h:outputText value="&#160;" />
                <h:outputText value="&#160;" />


                <p:commandButton value="#{msg['save']}" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-check" validateClient="true"
                                 actionListener="#{projectBean.addProject}" style="left: 312px;" >
                </p:commandButton>

            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
    </h:body>
</ui:define>
```

method:

```
 public void addProject(){
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "You voting is saved", "Thank you for you chose");

    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().showMessageInDialog(message);
 }
```

I think that problem is in panel or panelGrid. But on the other hand, method work from this possition. Could anybody please help me with this issue

Comment: Find the differences...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. It was - ajax="false". I delete it, and message is shown